# how to password protect Elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-x-pack

I have Es version 7.6.2 I saw on website that from version 6.2 onwards x-pack is included by default but i was not able to find or enable x-pack for security. how do i enable password protection in Elastic search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per elastic search [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/blog/getting-started-with-elasticsearch-security)

> The first thing you have to do is download the default distribution of
>   Elasticsearch and Kibana version 6.8+ or 7.1+. Security was added to
>   the default distribution in 7.1 and 6.8, so if you’re on an older
>   version, you’ll need to upgrade.

After downloading latest version , you need to enable xpack.security.enabled: true in elasticsearch.yml file

To generate passwords

```
elasticsearch-setup-passwords auto
```

in command prompt, your cmd path should be elasticsearch/bin. It will auto generate passwords for elasticsearch kibana etc. note them . 
If you want to provide your own username password instead of auto generated execute

```
elasticsearch-setup-passwords interactive
```

In kibana.yml update below two with user name and password for elastic search you got by executing set up password

```
elasticsearch.username: "<elastic>"
elasticsearch.password: "<password>"
```

Opening kubana it will prompt for username and password, enter password for "kibana" you got from set-up-password

Comment: I am able to password protect ES however my kibana is now asking for UID and password when opened. The ES credentials dont work on the kibana screen. What password does Kibana looking for ?

Comment: @rahul changes in es affect kibana too. you can execute elasticsearch-setup-passwords.exe in bin folder. It will automatically generate passwords for different users

Comment: I tried it and set passwords for following users in ES using   elasticsearch-setup-passwords.exe- apm_system, kibana, logstash_system, beats_system, remote_minitoring_user, elastic

Comment: however the Passwords i set for ES are not working when i try to login in Kibana

Comment: thanks for your prompt reply. I tried the password of kibana in the Kibana uid/password Webpage but it is not accepting it/.....screenshot at https://discuss.elastic.co/t/after-enabling-xpack-in-es-how-do-i-login-in-kibana/231530/6

Comment: @rahul can you mention the steps you have performed. 1 generate password using set-up password it will give password for elasticsearch, kibana, apm etc. 2. Update kibana.yml file with password for elasticsearch , the 2 lines I mentioned in answer. 3. Start kibana . Enter the username and password for kibana

Comment: its not working for me ...showing forbidden error after login ...see screenshot https://imgur.com/Wq9Ke0E

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213487/discussion-between-jaspreet-chahal-and-rahul).

Comment: Kibana user didnt had all privilages i think slastic user was able to login

Answer (score 0):

I am able to password protect ES however my kibana is now asking for UID and password when opened. The ES credentials dont work on the kibana screen. What password does Kibana looking for ?

Answer (score 0):

isseue resolved by using elastic user rather than kibana user